# SSHD formating during Windows 10 installation

Tags: windows, partitioning, installation, formatting, hybrid-storage

I am doing a clean install of Windows 10 on my HP Envy 17 j040ec laptop. It has a hybrid hard drive (1TB HDD+25GB SSD).

During Windows installation, I am offered the standard interface to format a organize disk space into partitions and then choose the partition to install Windows 10.

In there I can see both the 1TB and 25GB disks as a separate units, not just partitions.

The question is: For the correct workings of SSHD, should I:

1. format and remove the 25GB partition -> create 25GB of unallocated space on SSD

   or
2. create a 25GB partition from the SSD

In both cases I will of course install Windows 10 on the HDD. In BIOS there is Intel Rapid Storage - Enabled, and there is no RAID set up (even though there is the option to create RAID from those "two" disks).

Comment: From what I've read about that kind of hybrid drive a few years ago, the flash memory portion was completely controlled by the drive itself, used as a reboot surviving cache. What's your drive model, sounds new/different?

Comment: Well... first of all, I am not using the original HP setup, I use clean W10 instead, so there is a little chance, I broke some software/firmware coop. Those two drives were showing as LITEONIT LMS 24L6M-HP (SSD) and ST1000LM024. Now I installed Intel Rapid Storage Driver and configured it to "speed boost of HDD using the SSD" and it seems to take care of that... now I see only the main drive.

Comment: Looks like a strange setup, separate hard drive & that little SSD. The rapid storage driver seems to use the SSD like the bulit-in hybrid drives do. But SSD's are supposed to be much faster when hosting an OS, why not just put windows on the SSD? If you'll be using a windows disk cache I would **not** put it on the SSD, limited writes and all that